# Eclipse: enable assertions

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, assertions

I'm running Eclipse Galileo. How do I enable assertions in Eclipse?

As suggested by other sites, I've tried adding the arguments: `-ea`.  I have also tried changing the compiler compliance level to `1.4`. Neither of those suggestions worked.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

1. Go to the *menu* `Run`, and then to the *menu item* `Run Configurations`.

[image]

2. In the *left panel*, go to `Java Application`, and then go to `Assertions`.
3. In the *right panel*, choose the *tab* `Arguments`.
4. Under the *field* for `VM arguments`, type `-ea` to enable assertions.

[image]

5. Click on the `Apply` and then `Run` *button*.

---

To globally set it as the *default for everything*:

1. Go to menu `Window` (if you are on Windows), or go to menu `Eclipse` (if you are on Mac). For Linux it might be something similar.
2. Go to `Preferences`.
3. Choose `Java`, and then `Installed JREs` from the *left panel*.
4. Select your *JRE*, and then click the `Edit...` button in the *right panel*.
5. In the `Default VM arguments` field, add `-ea`.

Comment: This doesn't work for Android, you apparently need JUnit Assert.

Comment: To globally set it as the default for everything, go to Window -> Preferences -> Java / Installed JREs. Select the JRE and click "Edit...". In the "Default VM arguments" field, add "-ea".

Comment: @nbro I don't have an `Assertions` item under `Java Application`. Maybe you meant current run configuration?

Comment: @JohnMcClane It is possible that different versions of Eclipse have different panels, buttons and menus. If I specifically added that instruction (but it was a long time ago), it is likely the case that I tried it out on my own version (as you can also notice from the pictures, I am using a mac, so it is possible that Eclipse versions are slightly different on other systems).

Comment: @nbro Those items under `Java Application` on the picture are (presumably) project names. What if the current project has a name different from `Assertions`?

Comment: @JohnMcClane Yes, I think you're right. It's possible those were project names. Rather than going to "Assertions", you should go to your project name (I guess).

Answer (score 36):

If you want to solve this issue globally for all JUnit tests then go to `Preferences > Java > JUnit` and at the top click the checkbox for "**Add 'ea' to VM arguments when creating new JUnit launch configuration**" Now Eclipse won't bug you for every *new test* you want to run. For existing tests you have to remove their's run configurations in `Run Configuration > JUnit`.

Comment: Is there any way to add -ea to all _existing_ JUnit launch configurations?

Comment: To be added **-ea** to existing tests you have to remove run configurations in **Run Configuration > JUnit**

Answer (score 13):

To do this globally for all Java runs, edit the Installed JREs properties.

For example:  Windows -> Preferences -> highlight the default JRE -> click Edit... -> In the Default VM arguments input box, enter -ea -> click the finish button.

This worked on Eclipse Kepler SR2.

Answer (score 5):

On **maven** projects you can run **main method** with auto-magic classpath by:

```
bash> export MAVEN_OPTS="-ea" && mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.your.class.with.main"
cmd> set MAVEN_OPTS="-ea" && mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.your.class.with.main"
```

In linux/eclipse you can add terminal window with bash for more convenient use.

Answer (score 4):

You want to enable assertions for an application you're running from Eclipse?  I usually just add -ea to the command line parameters in the "Run As" profile.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I usually do it too when I'm running from the command line, which is why I thought adding those VM arguments in the preferences would work. Thanks for the input. In confirms I wasn't crazy for thinking that should do it..