# Weird behavior of assertions in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, behavior, assertions

I have found a strange behavior of assertions in Java (Eclipse). Easy example: If i execute this...

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    assert(getA() == "a") : "Invalid";
    System.out.println("Assertion successful!");
}

private static String getA() 
{
    return "a";
}
```

... it will show me "Assertion successful!" as it should. However if i try this...

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    assert(getA() + "b" == "ab") : "Invalid";
    System.out.println("Assertion successful!");
}

private static String getA() 
{
    return "a";
}
```

... I get an AssertionError. How come this Assertion doesn't return true?

**Note:**

- Don't forget to add the "-ea" Parameter in the VM arguments when testing! ([Eclipse: enable assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509082/eclipse-enable-assertions))

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: The real question is: why doesn't the first snippet print "Invalid"?

Comment: It has to do with an optimization in the JVM sp00m, in the first case the "a" literal each occupy the same memory space

Comment: when comparing Objects use Object.equals(Object o), == basically tests if the entities you are comparing are instances of the same Object

Comment: @sp00m: see Javiers answer.. oh man, I should better get more sleep^^

Comment: @John Kane: == tests whether or not 2 objects are the same object (occupy the same place in memory) not if they have the same type

Comment: If you think some core java function or library is behaving "weirdly" like assert. It is 99.999% of the time user error :)

Comment: @Cruncher yeah, sorry I should have explained that better. Instances of the same Object would be in the same memory location. I didnt mean to imply type. Thank you for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to give

```
"a".equals(getA());
```

Second case

```
"ab".equals("b".concat(getA()));
```

**Reason:-** `==` is for comparing object references, whereas `equals()` is used for the string value comparison, which is what you needed. Plus, the first scenario had the same string literal "a", hence, it returned `true`. But in the second case, a new instance of String was created for `getA()+b` , which is different from the literal "ab".

Comment: Beat me to it lol.

When you do == it does object compare opposed to string value comparison. This can lead to strange comparisons.

Comment: Oh noes, that was it! Thank you, that was embarrassing! :D

Comment: well, what about this example here? why does this fail? http://pastebin.com/ZgA6bTjw

Comment: @RomanMächler In that example you are comparing two string arrays... completely different case. See this link for the answer to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777257/equals-vs-arrays-equals-in-java

Comment: np, I think a variation of this question appears at least once a day on SO :)

Answer (score 5):

`"a"` is a literal on compile time, then `"a"=="a"` evaluates as `true`

`getA()+"b"` creates a new instance of String, which is different from the compile time literal `"ab"`