# What can be entered in the unknown area to make the assertion true?

Tags: java, assertion

This is a test question. I can add to the [???] but can't edit the rest of the code. What should I add?

```
class Primary{Primary(String name){this.name=name;}String name;}

class Secondary extends Primary{[?????]}

public class Exercise{

  public static void main(String [] arg){
    assert (!new Secondary().name.equals(new Secondary().name));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer that strictly makes changes only to the [???] part of your question:

```
class A{A(String name){this.name=name;System.out.println(name+" <-- name");}String name;}

class B extends A{
    static int instanceCount = 0;
    public B() {
        super(instanceCount++ % 2 == 0 ? "CandiedOrange" : "uttp");
    }
}

public class Exercise{

  public static void main(String [] arg){
    //assert(false);
    assert (!new B().name.equals(new B().name));
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
CandiedOrange <-- name
uttp <-- name
```

What's happening is the static `instanceCount` int's value is being shared among all `B` instances.  They all point to the same bit of memory.  If it wasn't static each `B` instance would get their own memory for instanceCount and none of them would ever have a value greater than 1.

Since `instanceCount` gets incremented every time an instance of `B` is constructed it's keeping track of how many `B` instances there are.

The `% 2` means divide by two and tell me the remainder.  The remainder will always be 1 or 0.  When it's 0 you get my name.  When it's 1 you get uttp's.  These names are not equal so the assert will pass.  The ! negates the rest which is only true when they are equal.  Thus, it asserts the names should not be equal.

I did say I'd only change what was in the [???] but you can remove the `println` since it's just debugging code.

Make sure the test fails when you remove the comment in front of `assert(false)`.  If not you likely need to add -ea to your vm arguments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5509180/1493294

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your question is not clear. The asseration may be always false, except that you change the constructor of the B.

```
public class Test {
 class A{
     String name;
     A(String name){
         this.name = name;
     }
 }

 class B extends A{
     B(String name){
         //super(name + "something else"); //asseration will be true.
         super(name);
     }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
     Test t = new Test();
     A a = t.new A("uttp");
     B b = t.new B("uttp");

     System.out.println(!a.name.equals(b.name));
 }
}
```