# Using recursion to create a power method

Tags: java, recursion, this, pseudocode

I am very new to programming, and Java is my first real language. At this point in class we are touching on recursion, and have been asked to make a method that fits certain parameters:

The method is as such: public void power(int p) where we cannot change the formal parameters of the method. I've looked into this elsewhere and it seems that a lot of solutions involve adding the int n (for the number to have the power performed upon) as a parameter.

When writing similar methods we were encouraged to use "this" as our representation of what we are trying to change. Normally "this" is used in instance methods i.e.: this.increment().

When I write pseudocode for it I find I want to do the following:

```
public void power(int p) {
    assert p >= 0 : "Violation of: p >= 0";
    int x = 0;

    if (p == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (p % 2 == 0) {
        x = this.power(p / 2);
        return x * x;
    } else {
        return this * this.power(p - 1);
    }
```

I just don't know how to write it so that it can actually run with eclipse and java. Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: `return this * this.power(p - 1);` looks weird

Comment: This is not pseudo-code, this code compiles (almost). What is the use of a power method returning void ? You should return a result. And as Benj pointed... the last line is weird. What is the class you are working on, give us some context

Comment: And you need to provide the value that is being raised to the power. Is it meant to work as an operator?

Comment: well, this **is** java-code (though it won't compile. apart from that you'll encounter some problems: `x ^ y` is a binary operator (always 2 arguments). you should clarify what you actually want to achieve before asking a question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I am given a java program to actually call my method and test it with given inputs for n ( or as I called it x) and p. That is what I have to go off of to see if my code actually works. So it will return a value once I run it in my other code.

The class I'm in is the first in a series for computer science engineering where we are learning the basics as far as constructors, methods, objects, recursion, and the like. I am really having a difficult time with being able to execute what I "see" should work.

Comment: yes, but what does your code have to achieve in order to 'work' ? what are you trying to compute? what is `power(p)`?

Answer (score 2):

The following stop condition is wrong, it should return `1`.

```
if (p == 0) {
  return 0; // should return 1
}
```

If you use `this`, you cannot use multiplication operator `*` in Java. You can have a `multiplyBy` function that should not mutate the callee:

```
public int multiplyBy(int x) {
    return this.value * x;
}
```

And as you can see in the above method, you need to have an instance property for storing your integer value. So your code would now look like:

```
public void power(int p) {
  assert p >= 0 : "Violation of: p >= 0";
  int x = 0;

  if (p == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (p % 2 == 0) {
    x = this.power(p / 2);
    return x * x;
  } else {
    return this.multiplyBy(this.power(p - 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: There's the correlation I was missing! I did not realize that when I use "this" I cannot use *.  In what way would this mutate the callee? Also thinking of instance properties as a way of storing my integers is a great way of thinking about it.

Comment: The following would mutate the callee which would have broken your recursion: `this.value = this.value * x;` in `multiplyBy`.

Comment: Using `this` with `*` operator requires an operation overloading mechanism which doesn't exist in Java, but exists in languages like C++ and swift and many others.

Comment: that's fascinating, it also makes a lot of sense now why we were directed to really only use multiplyBy10( ), divideBy10( ), and isZero( ) in this code. These are API specific to our school's library.

Answer (score 1):

When doing recursion, you have to think of two things.

- **Base case**:  When do you stop recursion?
- **Recursive case**:  When do you continue?

For a power, consider that it can be defined like this:

```
pow(x, p) = x * pow(x, p-1) if p > 0 else 1
```

The reason for that:

- x<sup>2</sup> is x * x.
- x<sup>0</sup> is 1.

So, with that in mind, let's consider some edge cases.  We don't want to accept any values that are negative for this scenario, so the `assert` works okay.  It'd be better to use an exception for this since not everyone is [going to enable assertions with the `-ea` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509082/eclipse-enable-assertions).

```
public long power(int x, int p) {
    if(p < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("p is negative, not allowed");
    }
    if(p == 0) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return x * power(x, p - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: ***Phenomenal*** point.  I hadn't realized that the method only allowed for one parameter, and yes, it turns into factorial.  Let me get some things straightened out about that.

Answer (score 1):

I would make the method `static` (so you don't need an instance). Pass in the value you want to raise to a power and the exponent. Something like

```
public static long power(int n, int pow) {
    assert pow >= 0 : "Violation of: pow >= 0";
    if (pow == 0) { // <-- n^0 = 1
        return 1;
    } else if (pow == 1) { // <-- n^1 = n
        return n;
    }
    return n * power(n, pow - 1); // <-- recurse
}
```

### As an instance method

Normally I would use [`Math.pow(double, double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29) but if you really need an in-place recursive implementation then you could do something like

```
class Power {
    public Power(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
    private int n;
    private long result = -1;

    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(result);
    }

    public long getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public long power(int pow) {
        assert pow >= 0 : "Violation of: pow >= 0";
        if (pow == 0) { // <-- n^0 = 1
            return this.result = 1;
        } else if (pow == 1) { // <-- n^1 = n
            return this.result = this.n;
        }
        return this.result = this.n * this.power(pow - 1); // <-- recurse
    }

    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would LOVE to do it this way, but we have to keep the method as is in the assignment. I think the whole point is he is trying to get us to utilize instance methods with "this" - and then calling that stored value later.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this.

```
class Ideone  
{   
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception  
 {

    Test t = new Test(2);
    System.out.println(t.power(5));
 }
}


class Test
{
int n;
Test(int n)
{
    this.n = n;
}
public int power(int p) {
 int x = 0;

 if (p == 0) {
    return 1;
 }
 if (p == 1) {
     return this.n;
 }
 if (p % 2 == 0) {
    x = this.power(p / 2);
    return x * x;
 } 
 else {
    return this.n * this.power(p - 1);     
     }      
}}
```

You can check this out at https://ideone.com/0ghIVe .

Comment: I have to return it as void though, what way would you suggest this. I wish I could return an integer value.

Comment: @Tori: If you want to implement this using recursion, you have to use some return type.You can't do it using void as return type.Are you clear with the requirements?